# Separate files to load or long line of code

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

http://rich.littlebigfoot.org.uk/test7.html

I am creating a map and will be loading 20 or so walks onto the map. Each walk will have upwards of 50 plus points which will create a very long file. Is it better to create a separate file for each walk, aiding any editing needs or just load one very long one please?

If I create separate walk files do I simply call them normally.

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20 paths with ~50 points each (i.e. 20*50 = 1,000 pairs of coordinates) is not that very long / big, actually. See for example [this GeoJSON file](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries.geo.json) with shapes of all countries in the world: it has 10k+ points.

A good practice is indeed to separate your data and application in different files, so that you can update them separately.

Then splitting again your data into separate paths is up to you, depending on the rate at which you will update them, if you have an automated process (or not) to generate them, and if your visitors are limited in terms of bandwidth. Just consider the benefit of caching on user's browser what does not change v.s. number of network requests to download separate files.

By the way, note that you can build a Polyline by [passing an array of "array of coordinates"](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng), you do not have to build actual `L.latLng` points:

```js
var polyline = L.polyline(
    [
        [50.2184,-5.4793],
        [50.2166,-5.4850],
        [50.2168,-5.4884] // etc.
    ],
    polylineOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have started to separate the files. It is actually easier to add walks now. Thank you for your second tip as well. I will be attempting that method next.